# A valid memory location in a user process is mapped at least twice, and why?

Tags: memory, operating-system, mapping

In OS, every valid memory location in a user process is mapped at least twice, once in the user process virtual memory, and once in the direct physical mapping in the kernelspace.

How to understand the "direct physical mapping in the kernel space"?

Answer (score 0):

It's all how you look at things. I would not describe this as a dual mapping but I guess you could do so.

If you are going to view this as a dual mapping, you'd view it as:

Step 1: Create the page table entry for the process.

Step 2: Map the page table entry to a physical page frame.

You could view the mapping as a one step process or even as a three step process.